# How to get data from listview/gridview and populate another listview/gridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

Using the XAML listview/gridview with binding I populate grid using linq query and C# code:

```
                AdventureWorkEntities awDatabase = new AdventureWorkEntities();
                var products = from p in awDatabase.Products
                               from i in awDatabase.ProductInventories
                               where p.ProductID == i.ProductID && p.ListPrice > 0
                               && p.Name.Contains(search.Text.Trim())
                               select new
                               {
                                   p.ListPrice,
                                   p.Name,
                                   p.ProductNumber,
                                   p.DaysToManufacture,
                                   i.Quantity
                               };

                IListSource query = (IListSource)products;
                ProductsList.ItemsSource = query.GetList();
```

I noticed a double click event for selected items.  What is the syntax to be able to double click a row and transfer that row into another grid below it?

The jist is that I'd like to be able to add one row from one grid to the other grid by double clicking the selected item from one grid.

Edit: XAML Code:

```
 <ListView Name="ProductsList"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DataContext="{Binding}" 
                  Margin="6,76,6,220" Width="726" MouseDoubleClick="ProductsList_MouseDoubleClick">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn  Width="85" Header="Product Number"
                                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductNumber}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="225" Header="Name"
                                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="135" Header="Days To Manufacture"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DaysToManufacture}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="75" Header="Quantity"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="75" Header="List Price"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ListPrice}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And my Attempt:

```
        private void ProductsList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //code to place the contents of top grid to bottome grid

        List<IQueryable> selectedContents = new List<IQueryable>();
        selectedContents.Add((IQueryable)ProductsList.SelectedValue);
        IListSource query = (IListSource)selectedContents;
        OrderContents.ItemsSource= query.GetList();
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide lot more data here. You're saying listview or grid, and what kind of data you've bound here? is it a table? list? or any custom objects.

Comment: I've displayed the code I'm working on.  I need to be able to select a row from one grid and place it into another grid exactly like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of knowledge of the syntax prevented me from figuring out this one liner.

```
        private void ProductsList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //moves items from top grid to bottom grid
        OrderContents.Items.Add(ProductsList.SelectedValue);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Observable Collection of the Entity ...and in the Double click event get the selected entity from the listView and add the selected Entity into that Observable Collection and bind the collection with the second listview....

Comment: By making an Observable Collection of the Entity, do you mean make a class of the data and place it in a collection?